# Send response from servlet to ajax call as object

Tags: jquery, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

I am communicating servlet to jQuery in following way.

**jQuery:**

```
$('.snd').click(function (){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ProjectName/ServletName?action=test',
        data: {cl1: $('.t11').val()},
        success: function (response){
            $('.t12').val(response);
        }
    }); 
});
```

**Servlet**

```
if (action.compareTo("test") == 0) {
            action = "abc";

            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
            PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

            try {

                out.println("text1");
            } finally {
                out.close();
            }
        }
```

By doing this I am getting the result "text1"

Now what do I need to do if instead of sending normal text I want to send an object or an String array to the jQuery as response?

e.g

in servlet I have the following array

```
String[] ss= {"n1","n2"};
```

and in jQuery I want to use

```
$('.t12').val(response[0]);
```

to get result "n1"

Comment: HTTP only sends and receives strings. It's up to you to determine how those strings are interpreted, e.g., JSON or other forms of type conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't send objects directly between server and browser, but what you can do is serialize them into the JSON text format (that's what JSON was invented for).  `JSON.serialize()` (or equivalent in other languages) on the server side and `JSON.parse()` on the client side.

If you specify the data type as JSON in the jQuery ajax call, it will automatically parse it for you so you don't even have to call `JSON.parse()`.